# enum stores data remains stored in the static variable of an enumeration even if the view controller dismisses

Tags: swift, enums, retain-cycle, strong-reference-cycle

I have a problem and do not know what to do.
My `FirstViewController` calls with

```
let secondVC = SecondViewController()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
self.present(navController, animated: true)
```

my `SecondViewController`.
In the `SecondViewController`, user can make various selections, such as selecting numbers.
The selected numbers are stored in a static variable of an enum located in the `SecondViewController`. (Why I do it this way is not important right now).

```
enum Numbers {
     static var selectedNumbers: [Int] = []
}
```

If I return to my `FirstViewController` with dismiss the `SecondViewController` and then go back to my `SecondViewController`, I see that the enum from the `SecondViewController` still has the user's selection stored.
What exactly is the reason for this? And can I somehow prevent or solve this?

Comment: What do you expect in this scenario? Static variable means available in all app lifetime

Comment: I expected it to be empty. Because the enum was created in the SecondViewController, this is emptied when the ViewController is dismissed, I assumed. The enum is only accessible in this ViewController.

Comment: “Why I do it this way is not important right now” it’s actually entirely important, as you’ve seen. A static variable on a struct, class or enum is just a global variable, but with slightly better organization (it’s filed alway under the type, rather than all under one global namespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your expectation, I recommend changing the static to store property in `SecondViewController`, and a callback to handle if needed, something like:

```swift
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    private var selectedNumbers: [Int] = []
    var onSelectedNumbers: (([Int]) -> Void)?
}
```

In `FirstViewController`, when you pop back from `SecondViewController`, handle selected here:

```swift
let secondVC = SecondViewController()
secondVC.onSelectedNumbers = { [weak self] numbers in
    //TODO:
}
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
self.present(navController, animated: true)
```

And if you still want to use static one, you can clear static property whenever `SecondViewController` is dismissed:

```swift
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    func dismissViewController() {
        //TODO: call this function manually
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            Numbers.selectedNumbers = []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for showing the different possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, no worries.